# Flash:  Improve performance by "breaking apart" graphics and creating symbols?

Tags: flash, performance, actionscript, graphics, adobe

### Question

In flash, if you have a complicated graphic (like a complex diagram) that doesn't change much and you want to move/zoom/rotate it around, then does Flash perform better if you convert all graphics into symbols?  Or does making symbols slow things down?

### Background

Sometimes, you do things for so long, you can't remember why you started in the first place.  Whenever I import graphics in flash (like from Illustrator, for example), I select everything, press cmd-B (or ctrl-B on Windows) repeatedly, "breaking apart" everything until I can't, anymore. Then I press F8 and create a symbol.

That's just what I've done for like the last 10 years.  It's to the point where I don't even think about it, anymore.  I vaguely remember doing this after learning that performance improves when you break apart graphics to create a symbol.

Now, I have a problem: I'm translating/rotating/scaling a massively complex, static diagram and it's too sloooow.  I'm trying every technique I can think of to speed things up—every little bit counts.

I've read [this link](http://codeidol.com/flash/flash-hack/Performance-and-Optimization/Optimize-Graphics-for-Performance/) and lots of others but I haven't come across the topic of creating symbols.

### Summary

Right now, I'm trying to figure out: should I go back through and make everything a symbol?  Should I go through and make everything *NOT* a symbol?  Which is faster?

All insights are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In flash, if you have a complicated
>   graphic (like a complex diagram) that
>   doesn't change much and you want to
>   move/zoom/rotate it around

usually makes me `BitmapData.draw()` it and remove the original instance from the display list. redrawing as the original instance changes appearance and zooming the `BitmapData` - if it doesn't have mousechildren

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, here. I'll look into that function, I'm assuming I can use it to make a quick bitmap out of a movieclip's contents? If so, then maybe I can create a bitmap, quickly, right before the user moves the clip. Then pull the movieclip offscreen, replace it with the bitmap, allowing the user to move the bitmap, instead, and then swap the movieclip back in once the user is done dragging the clip. Hmmm, sounds promising, I'm going to have to look into that.  As you mentioned, it won't solve my zoom problem but it might address translating the clip!

Comment: @gmale - you can scale your diagram without adding to the display list and draw the big version - imho should work

Comment: I'm liking this bitmap data thing. I did some google codesearches to see how people are using it. Seems complicated but it might solve my problems! Can't wait to try it...I'm scaling using a slider. I think what I might try is to scale the bitmap, allowing it to get pixelated, and then bring the movieClip back in when the user releases the slider. When movement/scaling is done, I have to bring the movieclips back because some of the children clips in the diagram are clickable and have rollover events. Of course, I don't need the mouse stuff during a move/scale operation.

Comment: apart from creating a bitmapdata and drawing the content into it (which is a good solution ), there's also a DisplayObject.cacheAsBitmap property that will create a bitmap copy of you clip. this will replace your complex graphics object with a rasterized version. you can then translate and rotate it but it is not recommend to scale it ; the rasterization will have to be done repeatedly at each scale change. so turn it off-> scale->turn it on.

Comment: well, this didn't answer my question (about the value of "breaking apart" graphics when creating symbols) but it did lead me to a perfect solution to my problem! So I'm accepting it!  I ended up making a really cool utility that allows me to "add mouse motion" to any display object with 1 line of code (via static function call). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!